# Problems with resources in Qt

Tags: qt, resources

I created a "qrc" resource file

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/pictures">
    <file>cards/2_of_clubs.png</file>
    <file>cards/2_of_diamonds.png</file>
    <file>cards/2_of_hearts.png</file>
    <file>cards/2_of_spades.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

the files are all pictures in a map called "cards". 
I them create an imageObject and try to load one of the pictures from the resources but it does not load. (it does if I write the direct path to it)

```
QImage imageObject;
imageObject.load(":/pictures/cards/2_of_spades.png");
ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(imageObject));
```

I am obviously doing something wrong. Please help :)

Comment: Where are the resource file and the image files stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `qrc` as prefix of any resource based path in `Qt`:

```
imageObject.load("qrc:/pictures/cards/2_of_spades.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code or your qrc file. So my thought is that maybe your configuration is not set up to process the file.

After you create a qrc file, you have to make sure that "rcc.exe" is run on your file.  This will generate a qrc_yourqrcfile.cpp file which must be included in your project.

If you are using visual studios and have the Qt Visual Studios Plugin, this should all be handled for you when you add the qrc file to the project. I say 'should', because occasionally it doesn't quite work.  If you are using VS, and the plugin, then try to remove the qrc file from the project and re-add it.

If you are using QMake then your pri file should contain a "RESOURCES" section where you need to list your qrc file  something like:

RESOURCES += yourqrcfile.qrc

Then QMake will handle all the rcc'ing automatically.

I hope that helps.